# How to introduce someone else's work?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, meaning-in-context

For my German class I need to study the life and work of an artist. I picked Gustav Mahler, and I've created a Spotify playlist with the Mahler's best introductory songs and symphony. The playlist name should be something like "An introduction: Gustav Mahler" or "Gustav Mahler: an introduction", both would work.

Currently the name of the playlist is: "Vorstellen: Gustav Mahler".

I'm almost certain this is not the correct form.

Comment: Not sure, whether it is relevant for your presentation: Gustav Mahler was from Austria.

Comment: Not relevant. The city Mahler was born would be in Czech Republic today :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting the name of the person introduced in front is typical:

> Gustav Mahler – Eine Einführung (Gustav Mahler – An Introduction)
>
> Gustav Mahler – Ein Überblick (Gustav Mahler – An Overview)

If you wanted to hint the audience, you may give a conclusion about his work:

> Gustav Mahler – Musik und Darstellung (Gustav Mahler – Music and Presentation)